# Episerver updating database via sql query

Tags: episerver

I have to import a large amount of data into an episerver instance. It's much too slow to do it via the API. I'm trying to update the database directly. I'm updating properties of a block, so I update tblContentProperty. The update works but I don't see the change in the CMS. So I am either updating the wrong thing, or it's somehow cached?

I don't think I am updating the wrong thing because if I update the property through the UI, I can see the property in tblContentProperty getting updated. But running the Sql query doesn't seem to get reflected in the UI.

Do I need to clear the cache somehow?

Comment: Yes, Episerver caches heavily content listings and content themselves; if you work directly with DB (and common advise - don't do that), easiest way is to restart site after that. If you do that on regular basis, like in scheduled job - then yes you need to clear cache; you can read this for example for inspiration https://world.optimizely.com/blogs/joe-mayberry/dates/2019/2/working-with-the-local-object-cache/

Comment: All content loads are cached, such as calls to `IContentLoader.Get` and `IContentLoader.GetChildren`. However, it shouldn't be too slow to update through `IContentRepository` (and it's a safer implementation), unless you have a lot of event handlers (such as indexing etc) happening. If so, for example Search & Navigation (formerly Find) indexing can temporarily be disabled during content updates. You could also programmatically clear the object cache (it uses the built-in caching mechanism in ASP.NET).